# String inside valueBox component with two formats

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

I'm writing a Shiny App and I have a valueBox element with the following code:

```
valueBox(
    formatC(category, format="d", big.mark=','),
    subtitle = HTML("This text should be large and red <br/> This text should be small and gray"),
    icon  = icon("user"),
    color = "green")
```

The part I'm interested is:

```
subtitle = HTML("This text should be large and red <br/> This text should be small and gray"),
```

What I want is for the code is to format the HTML tag such that the first part of the string should be large and red while the second should be small and gray. I'm using the br/ tag to keep the text in two lines.

Is this possible inside a valueBox component?

Answer (score 1):

You could apply some css with `style`.

```
subtitle = HTML("<p style = 'font-size : 30px;color : red'>This text should be large and red </p><br/> 
                 <p style = 'font-size : 10px;color : grey'>This text should be small and gray</p>")
```